# Bootstrap without rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I love bootstrap, but i'm trying to achieve something totally outsides its expected grid, which is to have cells stack under each other without grouped lines. Something like Pinterest, if you will.

Bootstrap normal grid:
[image]

Bootstrap no rows concept:
[image]

Perhaps the correct answer is "don't use bootstrap" but having built many sites with it, I would love to continue using it and find a way around this.

If indeed i should use another responsive framework with a grid system more like what I need, what would you recommend?

tia

Comment: i think you should checkout this - http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I don't understand exactly, can't you just alter the css to reduce row margins? Also, you can put multiple things in a row, and it will flow like you describe

Comment: i've seen masonry and i'm loving it and i think i can get it to play well with bootstrap, however i'm wondering if there's a pure bootstrap way.

Comment: @serakfalcon, yes multiple things in one row but in order to stack them, i still need to use rows. i.e. if i were to always break into smaller columns i would be fine.

Comment: no, you don't need to use rows at all. I'll demonstrate

Comment: @Evgeniy, as I cannot find a pure bootstrap solution, i'll accept masonry as an answer (please post it), since I got it to work by simply not using rows and still using the col-md-xx classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have to use JS to reach goal.

You can use following libs:

[Jquery Wookmark](https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery) - Light weight and fast. Used in myself resolving similar issue

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) - Flexible and reach functions one

[Mansonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) - Popular lib, similar to Isotope

Answer (score 13):

I've worked on a similar problem for a nested drag'n-drop box api with goal to be compliant with bootstrap grid on final render, the builder wasn't a bootstrap grid but a home made similar paradigm of bootstrap grid and I've fixed it with the CSS3 marvelous flexbox

take a look at [Solved by flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)

I have putted a root row (only one for multiline) and added a class to it which implement

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

eg:

```
<div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="col-6">Variable height content</div>
    <div class="col-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-12">...</div>
    <div class="col-3">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

and the css

```
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

this will have the effect to adjust automatically the height of all the box that is on same line to the bigger one

Comment: You are a genius! It must be in the core of bootstrap.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing, because OP wanted "no rows concept", "something like Pinterest", which I understand in the way that cells should not be aligned vertically, i. e. layout generally should not produce optical rows. However flex styling does produce optical rows, although it is not necessary to group cells into rows in the markup.

Comment: I think adding `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` rules is not necessary, because Bootstrap adds them automatically to the `row` element, i. e. "the effect to adjust automatically the height of all the box that is on same line to the bigger one" works natively without manual styling, see Bootstrap 4 fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6u0vs9rf/

Answer (score 2):

You could try inverting columns and rows in bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here with more text than the first content but it still needs some more</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
        <div class="row">Some content here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/154/) of this.

Comment: my problem here is that your columns can only get smaller. if i need to stack a wider column, i'll need a parent row, which breaks the vertical stacking.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to realize about the `col-(size)-(gridsize)` is that they will wrap left to right then top to bottom. So, if you make a `col` with  a grid size less than 12, other `col` will begin to wrap around. You can also nest them as needed to split up the page. So, it's possible to create a 'rowless' layout like so:

(this isn't an amazing demo but it illustrates that what you want is possible)
http://jsfiddle.net/7575A/1/

Comment: i either don't understand how you can make a pure rowless layout with correct stacking, or it seems that it's not a perfect solution, as the vertical gaps are not consistent.

Comment: the vertical gaps can be fixed by removing the padding on the `col` items

Comment: what I mean is that, after testing what you said, some of my "tiles" stack vertically and some of them break into a natural row. when i turn on masonry, this is fixed. thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

you can use row in col and then but new cols in these rows 
if you have problem in padding make your 
classes no-padding / no-left-padding / no-right-padding

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as per @gpantic's answer, this doesn't create the effect i'm looking for.