# Iterating every third row in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having some diffulculty iterating through my object. The thing is, what I want is to create a row with 3 columns and fill them with information from the controller.

```
<body ng-controller="StatisticsCtrl as statCtrl" ng-init="getValues()">
    <div id="contentWrapper" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4"  ng-repeat="category in categoryDictionary">

                <div style="background-color: #0d1224; border-radius: 10px; padding:10px; ">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12"><h4><span class="rubriker kategoriRubrik">{{category.rubrik}}</span></h4></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

what I do now is that i repeat within the creating of the column row, but thats not optimal for what i want. I want a row with 3 columns within. I've tried googling like crazy the entire day without finding any help. A working jsfiddle provided with my example code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried creating a table, it seems to me that is what you are looking for? also if you provide the columns you need I can then create a table example for you to work with.

Comment: You want to repeat this example for each 3 categories(27 categories = 9 rows), and repeat the columns inside the row until 3 categories. I'm following your idea?

Comment: to be clear: my categoryDictionary has 17 objects. so the first 5 rows will contain 3 columns, and the last row will contain 2 columns

Comment: could you share your object ?

Comment: klauskpm, exactly. I want the UI to be completley dynamic, so if i decide to add another category the UI could handle that without me adding any extra code to the view, just to the categorydictionary

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle of what you are doing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L1m5LLsg/ here you go. This is one column, so i want 1 row created, then 3 columns, then 1 row, then 3 columns and so on untill i've iterated through my entire categoryDictionary. It can contain 2 items, it can contain 40, shouldnt matter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573488/slice-by-index-with-increment/27573865#27573865 isnt this what u r asking?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607629/155687 It will wrap elements within the single row, and you can choose how many columns to display with `col-*` classes. All you need is to declare a `flex-row` class and add it to your row element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify this:

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
   $scope.categories = [
       { id: 1, name: 'A'},
       { id: 2, name: 'B'},
       { id: 3, name: 'C'},
       { id: 4, name: 'D'},
       { id: 5, name: 'E'},
       { id: 6, name: 'F'},
       { id: 7, name: 'G'},
     ];

     $scope.getRows = function() {
       var arr = [];
       for(var i=0;i<$scope.categories.length/3;i++) {
         arr.push(i);
       }
       console.log(arr);
       return arr;
     }
}]);
```

html:

```
  <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="index in getRows()">
       <div class="col1">{{categories[$index*3].name}}<div>other stuff of category e.g. {{categories[$index*3].somethingElse}}</div></div>
       <div class="col2">{{categories[$index*3+1].name}}</div>
       <div class="col3">{{categories[$index*3+2].name}}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

this code prints 3 categories in one row
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2OQ0b4kV4PwlbUmRlhK0?p=preview)

Comment: this doesnt work with my example really. I want to have 3 columns with alot of information ( jsfiddle.net/L1m5LLsg  here you can see how 1 column work). A category for me contains alot of information

Comment: @steffokeffo but You got this, You only have to extend my example

Comment: after some conclusion i feel that this solution is the best one, and the simplest ( even tho variablenames get unbareable :) )

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this question a few times over the last year.  Using Bootstrap, you **do not** need to manually separate your data into groups.

Bootstrap automatically wraps columns for you.  I have a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Rxm9oDFPWc) of this in action.

See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150361/display-three-columns-per-row-in-mvc-cshtml/27151113#27151113) as well.

**Edit**

If your rows are not of equal height, you may need to add a `<div class="clearfix" />` after every 3 columns, to "reset" the columns and fix alignment issues.

Comment: I tried this at first, but since my columns have different sizes the layout acted very strange. For example since my second column had a little more information , the height of the column extended down the second row which made it only room for 1 more column. So first row was 3, second row was 1, and then 3 again. If i have 3 columns per row this isnt a problem.

Comment: and you can easily test this by adding a height of 100px to one of your 3 first divs, then the result gets "corrupted"

Comment: you can use a clearfix div to reset the positions of the columns with varying row heights, I updated my answer.

Comment: i read about clearfix earlier, i still get the same type of results when i try to use it, nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you were avoiding it, but, sadly, you have to slice your object.

You need to create this **filter**:

```
gameOnApp.filter('group', function() {
    return function(categories, size) {
        var categoriesGroup = array(),
            i = 1;
        while(categories[size*(i-1)]) {
            categoriesGroup.push(categories.slice(size*(i-1), size*i));
            i++;
        }
        return categoriesGroup;
    }
});
```

And modify your HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4"  ng-repeat="categoryGroup in categoryDictionary | group:3">

    <div style="background-color: #0d1224; border-radius: 10px; padding:10px; ">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="category in categoryGroup">
                <h4>
                    <span class="rubriker kategoriRubrik">{{category.rubrik}}</span></h4></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

To highlight what you need to change, follow this:

> div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4"  ng-repeat="**categoryGroup** in categoryDictionary | **group:3**"
>   div class="col-xs-12" **ng-repeat="category in categoryGroup"**